# Flutter Integration with Firebase Build Gradle Error

Tags: flutter, firebase

I am trying to integrate my application developed on Flutter with Firebase, however while following the tutorial, I'm facing some issues.

Copying exact thing from Firebase documentation:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    id("com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15") version "4.3.15" apply false
}
```

Updating them with some solutions found:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms.google-services:4.3.15'
}
```

I'm still facing the issue in Build. I have also checked the google-services.json file which is in app folder and the build gradle inside it looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"


dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.1.1"))
}
```

Comment: Sometimes build fails since you do not have a compatible JAVA version installed. Also check that the version is the one gradle needs. I faced a similar issue before while updating an old project of mine and that was the issue.

Comment: what is the error message on the gradle tho ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to edit your `build.gradle` files manually to add firebase to your Flutter project nowadays. Use the Firebase CLI instead, just follow the instructions on this page:
[Add Firebase to your Flutter app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=ios)

This is what I did last time, and I had no problems at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use Firebase CLI to integrate flutter with firebase. See there documentation and follow step by step. Links: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#sign-in-test-cli